# How to allow an account to withdraw from another one?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, contract-deployment, timestamp, block-interval

The goal is to create a contract which allows party B to withdraw from party A's account according to some formula. I don't want to use an escrow model, rather just to:

1. Let A attest that they are okay with B withdrawing at some future point in time.
2. Set a threshold for how much/ long B can withdraw.

Are there any examples or best practices for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't withdraw from someone else's account directly. You can, however, create a smart contracts in which A can deposit the money. Then, B is allowed to withdraw the money from the smart contract for a certain period of time. Of B hasn't withdrawn the money and the period has ended, A can withdraw the money from the smart contract

Answer (score 2):

I recomend using a Vault. You may check OpenZeppelin RefundVault.  Users send some funds to this Vault and depending of your business logic, user can request a refund and withdrawl funds.

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/v1.10.0/contracts/crowdsale/distribution/utils/RefundVault.sol

Answer (score 1):

For ERC20 tokens, you can use the `approve` function to allow someone else to withdraw from your token holdings:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md#approve

> Allows `_spender` to withdraw from your account multiple times, up to
>   the `_value` amount. If this function is called again it overwrites the
>   current allowance with `_value`.

For Ether, you can set up something like a multi-signature wallet where individuals have access to the same funds stored in that contract. This contract may not work exactly as you intend out of the box, but should be a great start:

https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet

Comment: Cool, thanks! I suppose I could also use [WETH](https://weth.io/) instead of the multisig wallet?

Comment: I am not verify familiar with WETH, but I assume you should be able to answer your own question since you are the one looking for a specific functionality.